# Solving set of equations and missing some solutions

Tags: equation-solving

This is a more general question about how Mathematica solves sets of equations and how can I assure that I get all solutions of my problem.

When I want to solve a set of equations, for example:

```
dX =  X (1 - X - Y) (1 -  Ryx Y)
dY = (1 - X - Y) (Rxy X  - Ryy Y)

(for dX and dY == 0)
```

I always use Solve[]. But for this set I got the following Warning Message

```
Solve[dX == 0 && dY == 0 , {X, Y}]
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
{{Y -> 1 - X}, {X -> 0, Y -> 0}, {X -> Ryy/(Rxy Ryx), Y -> 1/Ryx}}
```

I googled the message and found a solution using Reduce[]

```
Reduce[dX == 0 && dY == 0 , {X, Y}]
(Ryy == 0 && X == 0) || (X == 0 && Ryy != 0 && Y == 0) || 
(Rxy Ryx != 0 && X == Ryy/(Rxy Ryx) && Y == 1/Ryx) || 
(Ryy == 0 && Rxy == 0 && Ryx != 0 && Y == 1/Ryx) ||  Y == 1 - X
```

If I do some pencil and paper calculations I get the following set of solutions

```
{{X -> 0, Y -> 0}, {X -> 0, Y -> 1}, {X -> 1, Y -> 0},
{X -> Ryy/(Rxy Ryx), Y -> 1/Ryx}, {X -> (Ryx-1)/Ryx, Y -> Y -> 1/Ryx},
{X -> Ryy/(Rxy+Ryy),Y -> Rxy/(Rxy+Ryy)}}
```

So how can I be sure Mathematica gives me the full set of solutions?

Comment: `Solve` makes some compromises for the sake of efficiency and convenience, and may not return all solutions.  It may also return solutions that aren't valid for all parameter values.  This is described in the documentation, under Details and it is also shown in some of the examples.  `Reduce` is meant to return complete and fully correct solutions, but it can be very slow.  Try to keep the number of parameters to a minimum with `Reduce`.  Also try to tell it about any conditions (who is real, who isn't). This may speed it up, but it may also slow it down, depending on the situation.

Comment: However, what is happening in your example is that the equations are not independent, thus it can only solve for one variable.  `Y == 1-X` will satisfy the equation for any `X`.

Comment: I forgot tot say that you can also use the `MaxExtraConditions` option in `Solve`, which lets it generate conditions under which the different solutions are valid.

Comment: Ok, I see that 2 of my solutions are special cases of Y == 1-X. Now I started a new calculation Reduce[dX == 0 && dY == 0  && Ryx > 0 && Ryy > 0 && Rxy > 0, {X, Y}] but it runs very longer (> 5min)

Comment: My knowledge is very lacking here, but I think that `Reduce` calls `CylindricalDecomposition` to deal with inequalities (whether these inequalities are explicit or implied by the problem). This function has double exponential complexity in the number of variables.  Thus try to keep the inequalities on parameters to a minimum.  Is the result from `Solve[..., MaxExtraConditions -> All]` not satisfactory to you

Comment: Your right, Solve[..., MaxExtraConditions -> All] might be the better solution. It took me a while to understand the result but it gives the results I'm looking for

Comment: one approach is to let reduce find the generic solutons, then simplify out the special cases : `Simplify[Reduce[{dX == 0, dY == 0}, {X, Y}], 
 Assumptions -> {Ryy > 0, Ryx > 0, Rxy > 0}]` gives what you want very fast.